# Access attributes from another table - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A user can have many mentors, a Mentor belongs to user

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :omniauthable

  validates :firstname, :lastname, presence: true
  has_many :mentors


  class MentorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_mentor, except: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
  before_action :is_authorised, only: [:lesson]
```

How can I show the mentor lesson attribute on the user page? I tried to do something like "#{@user.mentor.lesson}" but it doesn't work :(.

Thank you,

Lily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a User has many mentors, then `@user.mentors` will give you an `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`, with more than 1 record corresponding to each Mentor. You can access to each them but to get an specific attribute of Mentor you need to iterate over this collection, like:

```
@user.mentors.each do |mentor|
  puts mentor.lesson
end
```

What you're trying to do is the inverse of what you need to do, as one mentor belongs to one user, then you could `@mentor.user` and to get the specific user and query its attributes without having to iterate, but in your case is accessing the plural of mentor.

Comment: Can I just check if this i show should I add the bit to the page (sorry, I'm new to Rails)                                                                                               
    <% @user.mentors.each do |mentor| %>
       <% puts mentor.lesson %>
    <% end %>

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: SOLVED in the following way: 
<% @user.mentors.each do |mentor| %> 
   <%= "#{ mentor.knowledge }" %>
<% end %> Thank you!